# My rabbit gave birth 4 days ago, and I can still see babies moving in her tummy, will she have a double litter

Tags: rabbits, pregnancy

[image]

My friends rabbit gave birth to three healthy babies 4 days ago, but I can still see babies moving in her stomach, does she have a double litter? Or some late comers

Answer (score 2):

I have searched the internet for a while and could not find information about "late comers" or "double litters". So I have to think, there is nothing common like this.

I have found some information about bradytocia, which means the muscles to bring the babies out of the mothers body do not work well or with enough power. This can be the reason for death birth of the baby and is a high risk for the mothers health.

In general it is a high health risk, if things which are intended to come out of the body or do not belong in it, stays inside (for example constipation through false food or contamination like splitter and thorns). They would decay and be living space for bacteria, which poisons the animal.

**I think the best you can do is bring your rabbit to a vet!**